# Best strategy for creating MongoDB indexes for Parse Server?

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform

I have a Parse application with a number of possible queries triggered by Cloud functions. I understand that creating indexes can speed up those queries.  But I'm wondering what the best strategy for indexing is.

for example, let's say these are some typical queries:

```
new Parse.Query('Customer')
    .equalTo('email', email)
    .equalTo('zipCode', zipCode)

new Parse.Query('Customer')
    .equalTo('email', email)
    .equalTo('areaCode', areaCode)
```

I could make a compound index for every such query (email+zipCode and email+areaCode, etc), but I have a lot of different queries, so this would be difficult to maintain, and my understanding is that too many indexes can hurt write performance.

If I instead make a single index for every field that is included in queries (email, areaCode, and zipCode for these examples), will all these compound queries be able to make use of the single indexes?  I read about "index intersection" in the MongoDB docs, but it's not clear whether this is something that will happen automatically in a Parse query.

Comment: Index intersection will happen automatically but in very specific conditions. I wouldn't count on it. Think about selectivity - how many documents you have with same email, same zip, same area. Think about ordering. If you need to sort results, you'd better have an index on this field. Read answers to very similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62263023/what-is-the-correct-way-to-index-in-mongodb-when-big-combination-of-fields-exist/62281956#comment110181297_62281956

Comment: Learn about [prefixes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes) - a compound index email-zip will still be useful to some degree for email-area queries.