# Indexing in MongoDB Replica Set Cluster

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, replicaset

In my `replica set mongodb cluster`, a `read` query could occur:

```
- either on column1
- or on column2
- or on combination of column1 and column2
- or on combination of column1 and column3
- or on combination of column2 and column3
- or on combination of column1 and column2 and column3
```

Would it make sense to create 6 indexes for each case above or there is an efficient way to club these under lesser number of indexes?

Comment: Creating so many indexes can affect the write performance on your server. You can take advantage of [Compound Index - Prefixes](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/core/index-compound/index.html#prefixes) to design your index and the queries.

Comment: The Compound Index works as 'and' or 'or' ? I think if I create a compound index with column1 and column3, then query on only column1 might not be able to leverage this index.

Comment: There can be more than one compound index. Also, see the topics in [Indexing Strategies](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/applications/indexes/), like Create Queries that Ensure Selectivity. You may have to make some compromises and work with the design. It will be a little bit of "trial and error" process.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62263023/what-is-the-correct-way-to-index-in-mongodb-when-big-combination-of-fields-exist/62268015#62268015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index on `{column1: 1, column2: 1, column 3:1 }` can service queries on:

- column1
- column1 and column2
- column1 and column2 and column3

An index on `{column2: 1, column3: 1}` can service queries on:

- column2
- column2 and column3

An index on `{column3: 1, column1: 1}` can service queryies on:

- column3
- column3 and column1

All of your queries noted could be handled properly with 3 compound indexes.

If you do find it necessary to create lots of indexes, note that mongod has a limit of 64 indexes per collection.

Answer (score 1):

Create three indexes, one each for every field. Mongo is able to combine several indexes, see [Index Intersection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-intersection/)

Verify performance and have a look at execution plans (using `explain()`)

Comment: would it help to use hashed index for these? its a replica set cluster.

Comment: No, hashed index makes only sense for a sharding key field.